# Cannot SSH onto EC2 instance after CPM recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I restored an EC2 instance using CPM, and when I try to connect to the instance via ssh I get an operation timed out error. Any ideas? It's an Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Comment: Were there any changes to the public ip or security groups?

Comment: @datasage I just used CPM to directly recover the instance. There was no option to edit public IP's or security groups. The public IP *has* changed though - the broken instance is still there, it's just stopped. Recovering an instance from CPM just creates a new copy in EC2.

Answer (score 0):

This common issue is explored in great detail by Eric Hammond at http://alestic.com/2009/08/ec2-connectivity

Feel free to update this community wiki with relevant information after solving your problem.